# Google Streetview Images without direction or camera angle

Tags: google-api, google-street-view

Is it possible to get the image based on an address using the API? I have seen that it is possible to get them via latitude, longitude (which I do have) direction and camera angle (which I do not have).

I made some research and found posts from several years ago, which stated it would not be possible - but technology evolves and I wanted to know if anyone has an idea how to get an image based on the address.

Theoretically Google would be able to do that; they know where the images has been taken and can calculate the direction to the address.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is possible,

the nearest streetview panorama can be found via the API, and the heading to the actual position can be calculated.

As in this article:

[Google Maps Api StreetView PanoramaOptions Point of View Setting from Lon Lat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443241/google-maps-api-streetview-panoramaoptions-point-of-view-setting-from-lon-lat)